# Typescript discriminating union & JSX & Redux Connect error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have React component `ExerciseDumb` which has props `wholeExerciseIsTouchable` and `middleIsTouchable`. If middleIsTouchable is *true*  than wholeExerciseIsTouchable must be either omitted or *false* (and other way around)

Here are my typings:

```
interface IExerciseOwnPropsShared {
  id: number;
  renderTags?: boolean;
  renderValueDifference?: boolean;
  onTouch?: () => void;
  testID?: string;
}

interface IExerciseOwnPropsMiddleTouchable extends IExerciseOwnPropsShared {
  wholeExerciseIsTouchable?: Falsy;
  middleIsTouchable?: true;
  onMiddleTouch?: () => void;
}

interface IExerciseOwnPropsWholeExerciseTouchable extends IExerciseOwnPropsShared {
  wholeExerciseIsTouchable?: true;
  middleIsTouchable?: Falsy;
  onMiddleTouch?: () => void;
}

interface IExerciseOwnPropsJustLeftSectionTouchable extends IExerciseOwnPropsShared {
  wholeExerciseIsTouchable?: Falsy;
  middleIsTouchable?: Falsy;
  onMiddleTouch?: () => void;
}

type ExerciseOwnProps =
  | IExerciseOwnPropsMiddleTouchable
  | IExerciseOwnPropsWholeExerciseTouchable
  | IExerciseOwnPropsJustLeftSectionTouchable;
```

This is definition of `ExerciseDumb`

```
const ExerciseDumb: React.FunctionComponent<ExerciseComponentProps> = (props: ExerciseComponentProps) => { ... }
```

Also `ExerciseDumb` is connected to Redux:

```
const Exercise = connect<IExerciseFromReduxStateProps, IExerciseFromReduxDispatchProps, ExerciseOwnProps, IReduxState>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ExerciseDumb);
```

The problem is I cannot write `Exercise` component without both props `wholeExerciseIsTouchable` and `middleIsTouchable` even though they have been defined as optional and Interface `IExerciseOwnPropsJustLeftSectionTouchable` defines both of them as *Falsy*

For example if I write component like this:

```
<Exercise id={id} testID={id.toString()} />
```

I get error:

```
Error:(52, 11) TS2322: Type '{ id: number; testID: string; renderValueDifference: boolean | undefined; renderTags: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<(Pick<ExerciseComponentProps, "wholeExerciseIsTouchable" | "middleIsTouchable" | "id" | "renderTags" | "renderValueDifference" | "testID"> & IExerciseOwnPropsMiddleTouchable) | (Pick<...> & IExerciseOwnPropsWholeExerciseTouchable) | (Pick<...> & IExerciseOwnP...'.
  Type '{ id: number; testID: string; renderValueDifference: boolean | undefined; renderTags: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<(Pick<ExerciseComponentProps, "wholeExerciseIsTouchable" | "middleIsTouchable" | "id" | "renderTags" | "renderValueDifference" | "testID"> & IExerciseOwnPropsMiddleTouchable) | (Pick<...> & IExerciseOwnPropsWholeExerciseTouchable) | (Pick<...> & IExerciseOwnPr...'.
    Type '{ id: number; testID: string; renderValueDifference: boolean | undefined; renderTags: boolean | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Pick<ExerciseComponentProps, "wholeExerciseIsTouchable" | "middleIsTouchable" | "id" | "renderTags" | "renderValueDifference" | "testID"> & IExerciseOwnPropsJustLeftSectionTouchable>': wholeExerciseIsTouchable, middleIsTouchable
```

The strange thing is that I can omit both `wholeExerciseIsTouchable` and `middleIsTouchable` when writing  `ExerciseDumb` component, which is why I suspect this is some issue with Redux's Connect method. But I have no idea how to get around this.